# Check if function belongs to namespace or global

Tags: php, reflection

I need check if called function belongs to the current namespace or it is defined globally.

```php
<?php

namespace Test;

function is_string($str) { return false; }

var_dump(is_string('test'));  // will be always false, is the namespaced is_string()
var_dump(\is_string('test')); // will be the global is_string()
```

Now I need check if `is_string()` or `\is_string()` is defined inside the namespace or is global, and it will occur at the same file. Sometimes the namespaced version will not be defined.

I have tried to use the `ReflectionFunction` class, but it no works:

```php
var_dump((new \ReflectionFunction('is_string'))->inNamespace());      // returns false, instead of true
var_dump((new \ReflectionFunction('is_string'))->getNamespaceName()); // returns '', instead of 'Test'

var_dump((new \ReflectionFunction('\\is_string'))->inNamespace());      // returns true, that is right
var_dump((new \ReflectionFunction('\\is_string'))->getNamespaceName()); // returns '', that is right
```

Seems that it always points to the global, but when I just run `is_string()` it uses the namespaced version (that is correct on this context).

Answer (score 1):

That's because the name you pass to `ReflectionFunction`'s constructor is supposed to be a qualified class name, e.g. it doesn't know or care about the current namespace.

Here's a simple workaround that you could use:

```
/**
 * @throws \ReflectionException
 */
function getReflectionFunction(string $functionName): \ReflectionFunction
{
    $qualifiedFunctionName = strpos($functionName, '\\') === false
        ? __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $functionName
        : $functionName;

    try {
        return new \ReflectionFunction($qualifiedFunctionName);
    } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
        return new \ReflectionFunction($functionName);
    }
}

var_dump(getReflectionFunction('is_string')->inNamespace());        // true
var_dump(getReflectionFunction('is_string')->getNamespaceName());   // 'Test'

var_dump(getReflectionFunction('\\is_string')->inNamespace());      // false
var_dump(getReflectionFunction('\\is_string')->getNamespaceName()); // ''
```

Basically, what it does is:

- if the function name is qualified, it will simply pass it to `ReflectionFunction`'s constructor,
- if it's not, it will first attempt to find it in the current namespace, then in the root one (so that if you remove your custom `is_string` function, it will still fall back to the default one and give proper results).

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/S1hE2)